# jQuery ui catcomplete get data object in loop object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Referring from the below code. i use catcomplete from jQuery ui and i want to get the country list from each catagory to show up when seaching but i get undefined what i do wrong ?

This my object array:

```
24:category:"Afrika"
    country:1:{label: "Namibia"}
            2:{label: "Sydafrika"}
            3:{label: "Tanzania"}
            4:{label: "Madagaskar"}
25:category:"Asien"
    country:1:{label: "Private: Södra Indien"}
            2:{label: "Indonesien"}
            3:{label: "Filippinerna"}
            4:{label: "Indien"}
            5:{label: "Thailand"}
```

This my function:

```
 $('#autocomplete').catcomplete({            
         source: function (request, response) {
                //data :: JSON list defined
                response($.map(TourArea, function (value, key) {
                     return {
                         category: value.category,
                         label: value.country.label,
                     }
                 }));

         },
  });
```

Result is: country array get undefined
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEVh0.jpg)

Comment: what is `TourArea` in your code? is that your array? It's not clear. Anyway `value.country.label` doesn't exist in your array. `value.country[1].label` would be valid, I think. Or any other index of the country array. But judging by https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#categories I'm not sure this is really how the catcomplete functionality is designed to work.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6j6ebrLh/3/ demos a data structure which would work. It's hard to tell what to do with your data as above because what you've shown is not valid JSON and the structure is difficult to be certain about.

Comment: Thank @ADyson, do you have any idea to make it work? or good recommend for jQuery autocomplete searching with array object ?

Comment: Well I showed you a data structure that works in that JSFiddle link. You'll either have to build that structure yourself, or map your existing data into it. I would have done it for you but like I said, the array you posted above is not JSON and it's hard to be sure what the exact structure is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now i find out and it work. all i need is just merge all object to be in one.
[How to make multi id array object to all in one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897697/how-to-make-multi-id-array-object-to-all-in-one)

```
let newData = Object.values(data).map(v => {
let x = [];
for (let k in v) x.push(v[k]);
 return x;
}).reduce((c, v) => {
 c = c.concat(v);
return c;
}, []);
```

And autocomplete function:

```
$('#autocomplete').catcomplete({
   source: newData,
 });
```

Done all working fine.